# com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884

Tags: java, properties, batch-file, db2

Here i have probably a simple question.Im trying to connect to DB2 databvase and execute SPs through java.Im able to connect to the database but while executing the SP got the error.Please let me know how to solve this.By the way, im putting all the JDBC url,schema,usrname and password in a properties file and running a batch file

Here is the Stack trace when i ran the Batch file

```
URL :`jdbc:db2://ip:50001/RMSDB:currentSchema=etwrms;currentPackagePath=etwrms,sysibm,sysfun,sysproc;currentFunctionPath=sysibm,sysfun;

Santosh....after WF_NON_MSG_SEND

ERROR [main] WorkflowMailer (processcycle:344) - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQ
LSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=WF_NON_MSG_SEND;PROCEDURE, DRIVER=3.57.82
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=WF_
NON_MSG_SEND;PROCEDURE, DRIVER=3.57.82
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:676)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:60)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:127)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.km.c(km.java:2506)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.km.d(km.java:2483)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.km.a(km.java:1963)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.g(db.java:139)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.d(db.java:75)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.t.d(t.java:63)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.sb.k(sb.java:170)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.km.fb(km.java:1958)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.lm.kc(lm.java:2813)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.lm.b(lm.java:3515)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mm.Yb(mm.java:113)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mm.execute(mm.java:96)
        at com.ramco.rvw.workflow.mail.WorkflowMailer.processcycle(WorkflowMaile
r.java:338)
        at com.ramco.rvw.workflow.mail.WorkflowMailer.main(WorkflowMailer.java:6
5)
`
```

Answer (score 9):

The next time you get a DB2 error, you can go to this handy [error message website](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n440.htm) to find the reason.

### -440

NO AUTHORIZED routine-type BY THE NAME routine-name HAVING COMPATIBLE ARGUMENTS WAS FOUND IN THE CURRENT PATH

**Explanation**

An attempt was made to invoke a routine, but DB2® could not resolve the invocation of a routine, including the argument list, to a specific routine definition.

*routine-type*

The type of routine, such as FUNCTION or PROCEDURE.

*routine-name or schema-name.routine-name*

The name of the routine. If the originating statement references a qualified name, the routine name in the message text is qualified by the name of the schema.

**Possible causes for this error include:**

- The routine name was either incorrectly specified or does not exist in the database.
- A qualified reference was used, and the schema qualifier was incorrectly specified.
- The user's SQL path does not contain the schema to which the desired function belongs, and an unqualified reference was used.
- The wrong number of arguments was included.
- The right number of arguments was included in the routine reference, but the data type of one or more of the arguments is incorrect.
- The invoker of the routine is not authorized to execute the routine.

**Your Response**

Take a look at your SQL statement and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: What specifically did you do to make it work @SantoshKumar? What db2 jar file were you first using before? Having prob with this as well.